# Finding frequent users in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with columns named user_id and login_date, and I would like to get the ids of frequent users (i.e. logged in more than once) and the frequency of their logins.

To do this, I tried:

```
    frequent_users = df.groupby(['login_date', 'user_id']).agg({"user_id": lambda x: x.count()})
```

and the result is:

2011-01-17

```
          556     1
          456     1
          958     1
          374     2
```

2011-01-18

```
          789     1
          434     4
          654     1
```

The question is, how can I remove or filter out all entries that have frequency 1?

**EDIT:**

Here is an example:

```
    login_dates = ['2011-01-17', '2011-01-17', '2011-01-17', '2011-01-17', '2011-01-17', '2011-01-18', '2011-01-18','2011-01-18','2011-01-18', '2011-01-18', '2011-01-18']
    user_id =[556,456,958,347,347,789,434,434,434,434,654]
    df = DataFrame({'login_date': login_dates, 'user_id': user_id})
    frequent_users = df.groupby(['login_date', 'user_id']).agg({"user_id": lambda x: x.count()})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be simpler to use an apply here:

```
# instead of lambda x: x.count()
def count_more_than_one(x):
    c = x.value_counts()
    return c[c > 1]

In [11]: df.groupby(['login_date'])['user_id'].apply(count_more_than_one)
Out[11]:
login_date
2011-01-17  347    2
2011-01-18  434    4
dtype: int64

In [12]: df.groupby(['login_date'])['user_id'].apply(count_more_than_one).unstack(1)
Out[12]:
            347  434
login_date
2011-01-17    2  NaN
2011-01-18  NaN    4
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work, since c is an integer, not a list. If I define a result list and only return the results with counts > 1 I have the same list as above but with [] replacing 1s...

Comment: @Qbite ah, I meant value_counts (can you check if the edited version works?) ps. helps to provide a small example so we can check it :)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I get an error: ValueError: Function does not reduce. You are right, it's easier if I provide an example. Check the edited version of the original post.

Comment: @Qbite this seems to work with apply :s (Thanks for editing, makes it much easier, if I hadn't already +1d, I would again!) :)

Comment: Got it, the top option does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Swooping in to mention my favorite method...

```
frequent_users = df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: x.count() > 1)
```

Answering the second part of your question, "the frequency of their logins," is not so clear. Do you want average time between logins? Total number of logins?

Comment: I want the total number of logins per day (login_date) but from those I want to filter out any unique users, i.e. I only want to keep users with more than one login.

Comment: it seems like OP wants to chain a filter with a value_counts? (like you say, not clear!)